# Using Windbg to find the CPU core number which a faulting thread ran on?

Tags: windows-10, minidumps, windbg

I've been given a 20 core CPU with an intermittent fault on some core. Allegedly it's confirmed by Intel but no further details and not replaceable under warranty, or so Im told (I can't check now). CPU returned to owner and offered to me. If I disable that core in the BIOS I might have a free 19 core CPU. Fun times!

To identify the defective core prior to stress testing and use, I could run software repeatedly with affinity for one or few cores, and see which runs eventually fault. Or disable each core in turn in the BIOS. But

it seems more elegant to run something like 40 threads of prime95 or some other stressy software, or one prone to causing bugchecks on this CPU as a whole.  When  the system BSODs, I could in theory use WinDbg to find the faulting thread, and from that, the physical (or is it logical?) core it was running on at bugcheck, disable that specific identified core in the BIOS, and recheck CPU reliability, in case there's a 2nd defective core I don't know about.

I could run 20 copies of some single thread software, but I'd like to use this as a "teaching moment".

How would I use WinDbg on a crash dump, to trace the physical core number on which the thread ran which bugchecked?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a year late, but since no one answered. You can issue `!running -i -t` in a windbg debugger connected kernel or on a minidump, that will shows all thread callstacks running on logical cores.

*If you have 1 socket, with 4 physical cores, with Hyperthreading/Simultaneous Multi Threading, the OS will see 8 logical cores, hence you have 8 active threads.*

Here's a sample my target machibe:

```
6: kd> !running -i -t

System Processors:  (00000000000000ff)
  Idle Processors:  (00000000000000ba)

       Prcbs             Current         (pri) Next            (pri) Idle
  0    fffff80633125180  ffffa5067382c080 ( 8)                       fffff80635638400  ................

 # Child-SP          RetAddr               Call Site
00 ffffb585`704d6878 fffff806`35273151     0xfffff806`34f90003
01 ffffb585`704d6880 fffff806`3533591c     nt!HvcallpExtendedFastHypercall+0x51
02 ffffb585`704d6890 fffff806`35335b10     nt!HvlpFastFlushListTb+0xac
03 ffffb585`704d6950 fffff806`353355f3     nt!HvlpFlushRangeListTb+0x88
04 ffffb585`704d69b0 fffff806`352f9642     nt!HvlFlushRangeListTb+0x63
[..]
1c ffffb585`704d78b0 fffff806`356df621     nt!IopSynchronousServiceTail+0x2d8
1d ffffb585`704d7950 fffff806`3527ac15     nt!NtQueryVolumeInformationFile+0x431
1e ffffb585`704d7a10 00007ffb`4ec9c9e4     nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
1f 0000000f`24cfed48 00000000`00000000     0x00007ffb`4ec9c9e4

  1    ffff918159ea5180  ffff918159eb6240 ( 0)                       ffff918159eb6240  ................

 # Child-SP          RetAddr               Call Site
00 ffffb585`6e22f720 fffff806`3516269c     nt!PpmIdleGuestExecute+0x1e
01 ffffb585`6e22f760 fffff806`35161dee     nt!PpmIdleExecuteTransition+0x70c
02 ffffb585`6e22fa80 fffff806`3526ce88     nt!PoIdle+0x36e
03 ffffb585`6e22fbe0 00000000`00000000     nt!KiIdleLoop+0x48

  2    ffff918159f54180  ffffa506714860c0 (15)                       ffff918159f65240  ................

 # Child-SP          RetAddr               Call Site
00 ffffb585`6f42f920 fffff806`351b9ee7     nt!KeAbPostRelease+0x11f
01 ffffb585`6f42f970 fffff802`6a4f3f5c     nt!ExReleasePushLockSharedEx+0x37
02 ffffb585`6f42f9b0 fffff02f`9262d81a     dxgkrnl!CCompositionFrameCollection::FindCompositionFrame+0x9c
03 ffffb585`6f42f9f0 fffff806`3527ac15     win32kbase!NtDCompositionGetFrameSurfaceUpdates+0x14a
04 ffffb585`6f42fa80 00007ffb`4c8136e4     nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
05 0000000d`a5cff2b8 00000000`00000000     0x00007ffb`4c8136e4

  3    ffff91815a080180  ffff91815a091240 ( 0)                       ffff91815a091240  ................

 # Child-SP          RetAddr               Call Site
00 ffffb585`6e24f720 fffff806`3516269c     nt!PpmIdleGuestExecute+0x1e
01 ffffb585`6e24f760 fffff806`35161dee     nt!PpmIdleExecuteTransition+0x70c
02 ffffb585`6e24fa80 fffff806`3526ce88     nt!PoIdle+0x36e
03 ffffb585`6e24fbe0 00000000`00000000     nt!KiIdleLoop+0x48

  4    ffff91815a180180  ffff91815a191240 ( 0)                       ffff91815a191240  ................

 # Child-SP          RetAddr               Call Site
00 ffffb585`6e25f720 fffff806`3516269c     nt!PpmIdleGuestExecute+0x1e
01 ffffb585`6e25f760 fffff806`35161dee     nt!PpmIdleExecuteTransition+0x70c
02 ffffb585`6e25fa80 fffff806`3526ce88     nt!PoIdle+0x36e
03 ffffb585`6e25fbe0 00000000`00000000     nt!KiIdleLoop+0x48

  5    ffff91815a1d9180  ffff91815a1ea240 ( 0)                       ffff91815a1ea240  ................

 # Child-SP          RetAddr               Call Site
00 ffffb585`6e26f720 fffff806`3516269c     nt!PpmIdleGuestExecute+0x1e
01 ffffb585`6e26f760 fffff806`35161dee     nt!PpmIdleExecuteTransition+0x70c
02 ffffb585`6e26fa80 fffff806`3526ce88     nt!PoIdle+0x36e
03 ffffb585`6e26fbe0 00000000`00000000     nt!KiIdleLoop+0x48

  6    ffff91815a306180  ffffa5066f961040 (13)                       ffff91815a317240  ................

 # Child-SP          RetAddr               Call Site
00 ffffb585`6fa66df0 fffff802`6bf01497     kmsysinfo!GetProcTopology+0x2ab [C:\Users\qwe\source\repos\kmsysinfo\cpufeatures.c @ 703] 
01 ffffb585`6fa66ec0 fffff802`6bf0278f     kmsysinfo!GetCpuInfo+0x157 [C:\Users\qwe\source\repos\kmsysinfo\cpufeatures.c @ 782] 
02 ffffb585`6fa677e0 fffff802`6bf11020     kmsysinfo!DriverEntry+0x15f [C:\Users\qwe\source\repos\kmsysinfo\hpkmsysinfo.c @ 402] 
03 ffffb585`6fa678a0 fffff806`3579f72e     kmsysinfo!GsDriverEntry+0x20 [minkernel\tools\gs_support\kmodefastfail\gs_driverentry.c @ 47] 
04 ffffb585`6fa678d0 fffff806`3579ee6e     nt!IopLoadDriver+0x4c2
05 ffffb585`6fa67ab0 fffff806`3519b3c5     nt!IopLoadUnloadDriver+0x4e
06 ffffb585`6fa67af0 fffff806`35112ce5     nt!ExpWorkerThread+0x105
07 ffffb585`6fa67b90 fffff806`352709ca     nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x55
08 ffffb585`6fa67be0 00000000`00000000     nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x2a

  7    ffff91815a400180  ffff91815a411240 ( 0)                       ffff91815a411240  ................

 # Child-SP          RetAddr               Call Site
00 ffffb585`6e28f720 fffff806`3516269c     nt!PpmIdleGuestExecute+0x1e
01 ffffb585`6e28f760 fffff806`35161dee     nt!PpmIdleExecuteTransition+0x70c
02 ffffb585`6e28fa80 fffff806`3526ce88     nt!PoIdle+0x36e
03 ffffb585`6e28fbe0 00000000`00000000     nt!KiIdleLoop+0x48
```

What we see is 8 threads, and you can judge what they're doing based on callstack with public MS symbols loaded.

- Thread 0: something related to a NtQueryVolumeInformationFile and the hypervisor
- Thread 1: idle
- Thread 2: something related to graphics/directx
- Thread 3: idle
- Thread 4: idle
- Thread 5: idle
- Thread 6: my kernel driver I'm writing, hit a DebugBreak()
- Thread 7: idle

In your scenario the bugcheck will be clearly seen on a thread callstack.

I'm afraid I don't think windbg can present you with the physical core/socket, there aren't even any WDM APIs that give you this, even though WDM APIs may name KeQueryActive**Processors** and *processors related kernel APIs, they always return you the logical core info. Windows does not really distinguish between physical cores, only the BIOS does that.

However you can query this info directly from the chipset via CPUID.0xB calling OS APIs to set your kernel thread affinity iterating through all logical cores, querying x2APIC IDs, a bunch of crazy bit shifting as defined in intel-64-architecture-processor-topology-enumeration.pdf, then you can obtain package count (sockets), physical cores and logical cores. Unfortunately this all requires kernel code, and won't work on a minidump. *Maybe someone will enlighten me on windbg tips I didn't know about to do the above.*

Comment: Were you able to confirm a way to do this? I think it might be possible via https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-system_logical_processor_information , but I wonder if it corresponds directly to APIC ID that shows up in WHEA errors?  https://www.reddit.com/r/overclocking/comments/nv2vqu/whea_logger_apic_id_to_core_number_sanity_check/

My crash is on thread 11, I'm hoping that means core 5 (0-counted) is undervolted too hard.